# For url ending with special characters

Tags: .htaccess

How to show 404 error or page not found on url ending with special character through htaccess directive

For example

```
http://www.mysmartprice.com/%255C%2522 - this url shows 404 error
```

how to achieve to show 404 when url ends with special character

```
  %255C%2522
  %E2%80
  %E2%80%8E
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule as your very first rule:

```
RewriteRule %[0-9]+/?$ - [L,R=404]
```

Comment: Thanks once again anubhava - however this rule works well on home page, but does not well on inside pages of the site. how to make it work on all pages. rgds !!

Comment: Can you give some examples of those URLs that are not working?